# Joining data from 4 tables to calculate several weighted scores

Tags: mysql

Please consider the following tables.

`users` holds a couple of thousands of Twitter-users; their `tweets` are indexed with `sp100_id`, which is the id of the company (see `sp100`) the tweet was talking about. `tweets.class` holds the assigned sentiment class (`1` = neutral, `2` = positive, `3` = negative) for each tweet. `tweets.rt` holds the amount of times the tweet has been retweeted. Finally, each user has been given a `quality` score and a `follow` score, as follows:

```
users                       tweets
-------------------------   -----------------------------------------------
user_id quality follow      tweet_id sp100_id nyse_date   user_id class  rt
-------------------------   -----------------------------------------------
1       2.50    5.00        1        1        2011-03-12  1       1      0
2       0.75    1.00        2        1        2011-03-13  1       2      2
                            3        1        2011-03-13  1       2      1
daterange                   4        1        2011-03-13  2       2      0
----------------            5        1        2011-03-13  2       3      3
_date                       6        2        2011-03-12  2       2      3
----------------            7        2        2011-03-12  2       2      0
2011-03-11                  8        2        2011-03-12  1       3      5
2011-03-12                  9        2        2011-03-13  2       2      0
2011-03-13

sp100
----------------
sp100_id  _name
----------------
1         Alcoa
2         Apple
```

The desired output is a list per `sp100_id` per `_date` the amount of positive (`class=2`) and negative (`class=3`) tweets weighted per `rt`, 'quality' and `follow`:

```
sp100_id  nyse_date  pos-rt pos-quality pos-follow neg-rt neg-quality neg-follow
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         2011-03-11 0      0           0          0      0           0
1         2011-03-12 0      0           0          0      0           0
1         2011-03-13 5 (1)  5.75 (2)    11.00 (3)  3 (4)  0.75 (5)    1.00 (6)
2         2011-03-11 0      0           0          0      0           0
2         2011-03-12 3 (7)  5.00 (8)    10.00 (9)  5.00   2.50        2.50
2         2011-03-13 0      0.75        1.00       0      0           0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

(1) On 2011-03-13, 3 positive tweets for sp100_id 1. 1 tweet retweeted 2 times,
    1 tweets retweeted 1 time and 1 tweet retweeted 0 times = 2x2+1x1+1x0 = 5
(2) On 2011-03-13, 2 positive tweets made by user 1, who has quality 2.50 and
    1 positive tweet made by user 2, who has quality 0.75 = 2x2.50+1x0.75 = 5.75
(3) On 2011-03-13, 2 positive tweets made by user 1, who has follow 5.00 and
    1 positive tweet made by user 2, who has follow 1 = 2x5.00+1x1.00 = 11.00
(4) On 2011-03-13, 1 negative tweet made by user 2, retweeted 3 times = 1x3 = 3
(5) On 2011-03-13, 1 negative tweet made by user 2, who has quality 0.75, thus
    1x0.75 = 0.75
(6) On 2011-03-13, 1 negative tweets made by user 2, who has follow 1.00 so
    1x1.00 = 1.00
(7) 1 positive tweet which has been retweeted 3 times, 1 positive tweet without
    any retweets = 1x3+1x0 = 3
(8) 2 positive tweets from user 2 x quality 2.50 = 5.00
(9) 2 positive tweets x follow 5 = 10.00
```

I've tried to explain myself as good as possible. Who can help me build the correct query? As you can see, also dates for which there are no tweets (all values zero), need to be included in the resultset. I now have this, but am having trouble finishing the rest:

```
SELECT
    s.sp100_id,
    d._date,
    COALESCE(c.pos-rt,0)      AS pos-rt,
    COALESCE(c.pos-quality,0) AS pos-quality,
    COALESCE(c.pos-follow,0)  AS pos-follow,
    COALESCE(c.neg-rt,0)      AS neg-rt,
    COALESCE(c.neg-quality,0) AS neg-quality,
    COALESCE(c.neg-follow,0)  AS neg-follow
FROM sp100 s
CROSS JOIN daterange d
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        sp100_id,
        nyse_date, 
        COUNT(CASE class WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) * [rt]      AS pos-rt,
        COUNT(CASE class WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) * [quality] AS pos-quality,
        COUNT(CASE class WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) * [follow]  AS pos-follow,
        COUNT(CASE class WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) * [rt]      AS neg-rt,
        COUNT(CASE class WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) * [quality] AS neg-quality,
        COUNT(CASE class WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) * [follow]  AS neg-follow
    FROM tweets 
    GROUP BY sp100_id, nyse_date
) c ON s.sp100_id = c.sp100_id AND d._date = c.nyse_date
ORDER BY s.sp100_id, d._date ASC
```

Obviously, `[rt]`, `[quality]` and `[follow]` need to be replaced by correct syntax and I'm not sure about the `COUNT(...)` either, because it now first counts the number of tweets, but it should take every tweet apart and multiply it by its own number of retweets ('rt').

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Having some problem understanding your table footnote (1): the first tweet was retweeted twice; why is its contribution to `pos-rt` 2*2 and not 1*2, whereas the other two tweets (retweeted once and zero times) contribute 1*1 and 1*0 respectively?

Comment: In footnote (8), I think the relevant user had `user_id=2` with `quality=0.75` and therefore `pos-rt` should be `1.5`?  Similarly, for footnote (9) `follow=1.00` and therefore `pos-follow` should be `2.00`?

Comment: You were right on both accounts :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that I've understood the problem correctly (see my comments above), then you merely need group the joined tables and [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) the relevant fields where the tweets are of the desired class which can be determined using [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
SELECT      sp100.sp100_id                            AS `sp100_id`,
            daterange._date                           AS `nyse_date`,
            SUM(IF(tweets.class=2, tweets.rt,     0)) AS `pos-rt`,
            SUM(IF(tweets.class=2, users.quality, 0)) AS `pos-quality`,
            SUM(IF(tweets.class=2, users.follow,  0)) AS `pos-follow`,
            SUM(IF(tweets.class=3, tweets.rt,     0)) AS `neg-rt`,
            SUM(IF(tweets.class=3, users.quality, 0)) AS `neg-quality`,
            SUM(IF(tweets.class=3, users.follow,  0)) AS `neg-follow`       
FROM        sp100
       JOIN daterange
  LEFT JOIN tweets ON tweets.nyse_date = daterange._date
                  AND tweets.sp100_id  = sp100.sp100_id
  LEFT JOIN users  ON tweets.user_id   = users.user_id
GROUP BY    sp100.sp100_id, daterange._date
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9853/1/0).

[EDIT] Here's the `EXPLAIN`:

```
id select_type table     type   possible_keys             key        key_len  ref                        rows  extra
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  SIMPLE      sp100     index  NULL                      PRIMARY    4        NULL                        101  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE      daterange index  NULL                      _date      3        NULL                        147  Using index; Using join buffer
1  SIMPLE      tweets    ref    query,nyse_date,sp100_id  nyse_date  3        sentimeter.daterange._date 3815    
1  SIMPLE      users     eq_ref PRIMARY                   PRIMARY    4        sentimeter.tweets.user_id     1
```

Comment: Thanks, this is brilliant :-) Although my laptop (on which the query runs) times out, even with index on all fields. Perhaps I'll have to first make extra columns in `tweets` and fill in quality, etc. Then I wouldn't have to calculate on the fly by joining `users`  table....

Comment: @Pr0no: Take a look at the `EXPLAIN` output to see MySQL's execution plan for the query.  Chances are that your indexes need tweaking (simply building indexes on every column won't do much, as MySQL can only use one index for the query: you are better off building suitable composite indexes, but the order of constituent columns will be important).

Comment: Please refer to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c13fc I have added the necessary columns to the `tweets` table, making the `users` table obsolete. Could you update the query so I might try and run it? I will post the `EXPLAIN` for the original query also.

Comment: I have added the `EXPLAIN` to your post. Please see the update.

Comment: @Pr0no: Could you also show somewhere (perhaps by editing the sqlfiddle schema) the indexes that you have defined?

Comment: I don't know how to define it in sqlfiddle, but I have an index on every field you see in the sqlfiddle :-) In the mean time, thanks for your help btw.

Comment: @Pr0no: Then perhaps paste the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table?

Comment: See your updated post. I have removed some of the irrelevant columns. Perhpas it would just be best to rewrite the query now I have already added the `quality` and `follows` columns to `tweets` in the sqlfiddle? (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c13fc)

Comment: @Pr0no: Okay.  I think you need to create a composite index for `tweets` on `(sp100_id, user_id, nyse_date)`; I'm not sure whether the order will make much difference in this case (if it does, it will be related to the size of the respective tables: you'd probably want to join with the largest tables first, so the relevant column should be left-most in the index; perhaps someone else can help clarify here).